# javascript onClick=funct(this) replacement using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a clear replacement for the old `onClick=funct(this)` html event handler when generating code dynamically. The problem is that I can't seem to find one no matter how I look.

I'm creating a `<div>` tag as part of a function, and inside it is a `<a>` tag with a html event handler for onClick, where it passes itself as a parameter so I can find the related elements inside its `<div>`. But I know this is bad practice now, and I'd like to instead use the preferred addEventListener way, but I've no idea how to pass the caller into the function unless because as far as I know the following won't work.

```
renamehead.addEventListener('click', 'rename(renamehead)');
```

My current code: the js, and the html it generates.

```js
function makeActivity(name) {
  var act = document.createElement('div');
  act.setAttribute('class', 'activity');
  var acthead = document.createElement('div');
  acthead.setAttribute('class', 'acthead interface_element');
  act.appendChild(acthead);

  namehead = document.createElement('h3');
  var txt = document.createTextNode(name);
  namehead.appendChild(txt);
  namehead.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true')
  acthead.appendChild(namehead);

  var renamehead = document.createElement('a');
  txt = document.createTextNode('Rename');
  renamehead.appendChild(txt);
  renamehead.setAttribute('class', 'headcommand');
  renamehead.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
  renamehead.setAttribute('onClick', 'rename(this)');

  var delhead = document.createElement('a');
  txt = document.createTextNode('Delete');
  delhead.appendChild(txt);
  delhead.setAttribute('class', 'headcommand');
  delhead.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
  delhead.setAttribute('onClick', 'delActivity(this)');

  txt = document.createTextNode(' ');
  acthead.appendChild(renamehead);
  acthead.appendChild(txt);
  acthead.appendChild(delhead);

  var actions = document.createElement('div');
  actions.setAttribute('class', 'actactions');
  actions.appendChild(makeDropDiv());
  act.appendChild(actions);
  return act;
}
```

```html
<div id="activitydiv">
  <div class="activity">
    <div class="acthead interface_element">
      <h3>Record</h3>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="rename(this)">Rename</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delActivity(this)">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity">
    <div class="acthead interface_element">
      <h3>Stop</h3>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="rename(this)">Rename</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delActivity(this)">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `renamehead.addEventListener('click', function() { rename(renamehead); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in real functions instead, and you can simply use the local variables.

```
renamehead.addEventListener('click', function() {
  rename(renamehead);
});
```

You really don't want to pass a string the execute to `addEventListener`. Passing in a real javascript function will give you the flexibility you need here.

Comment: so they won't be out of scope when this gets called?

Comment: right, still relatively new to js, so I'm not sure what I can get away with and what will work.

Comment: @ForceGaia any functions declared in a scope will have access to any variables declared in that same scope, regardless of when those functions run. This is called a closure. Closure's are pretty sweet :)

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using .bind(),

```
renamehead.addEventListener('click', rename.bind(this,renamehead));
```

Here you can pass in the context you wish to be present for instance i'm using the same `this`.

This will keep the scope you require.

Comment: Why would you pass the function as a string?